# A few rate related problems.

Tags: calculus

These are a couple of rate related problems. One of them I do not know how to do. What is the diagram for the first one?

**1.**

A street light is mounted at the top of a 15-ft-tall pole. A man
6 ft tall walks away from the pole with a speed of 5 ft/s along a straight path. How fast is the tip of his shadow moving when he is 40 ft away from the pole?

*Answer Attempt:*

I'm a bit stuck on how to do this. I'm a bit thrown off on how to handle the parts that the man is 6 feet tall and 40 ft away but we're trying to find the rate at which the tip of his shadow is moving. Any hints?

**2.**

Two cars start moving from the same point. One travels south at 60 mi/h and the other travels west at 25 mi/h. At what rate is the distance between the cars increasing two hours later?

*Answer Attempt:*

So let's say w = distance west, s = distance south, and d = the distance between the two points.

$$w^2 + s^2 = d^2$$
$$2w\frac{dw}{dt} + 2s\frac{ds}{dt} = 2d\frac{dd}{dt}$$
$$2 \cdot 50mi \cdot 25\frac{mi}{h} + 240mi \cdot 60\frac{mi}{hr} = 260mi \frac{dd}{dt}$$
$$\frac{16900mi}{260mi} \cdot \frac{mi}{h} = \frac{dd}{dt}$$
$$65\frac{mi}{hr} = \frac{dd}{dt}$$

Comment: First one is a right triangle inside a right triangle sharing a common angle. You have similar triangles. The height of the the big triangle represents the light post and the height of the smaller triangle represents the dude.

Comment: regarding 2) you should have $\frac {16900}{260} = 65$ I think that this is just a transcription error.